# Validar filas en un Sudoku con python

Tags: python

Quiero que el código me valide las columnas de un sudoku, pero con el código que he hecho me valida las filas. Como lo puedo arreglar?

```
def validaColumna(t, col):
    numeros= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    if col in numeros:
        print ("Has escollit aquesta columna, validant...")
        numbers= ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        columna = []
        for i in range(len(t)):
            columna.append(t[i][col])
        validacio= set(columna)
        if len(columna) != len(validacio):
            print("La Columna tiene numeros repetidos")
            return False
        if not all(num in validacio for num in numbers):
            print("A la columna ni falten numeros`introducir el código aquí`")
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, esto no tiene sentido:

```py
numeros= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
if col in numeros:
```

Para hacer eso mejor usa este if:

```py
if 0 <= col <= 8:
```

O podrías hacer lo mismo con un `range`:

```py
if col in range(9):
```

Y ocurre lo mismo en esta línea:

```py
if not all(num in validacio for num in numbers):
```

En vez de poner los 9 números en un array a mano para hacer el bucle, es mejor usar la función `range`:

```py
if not all(num in validacio for num in range(1, 10)):
```

En este caso porque solo son 9 números y no es mucho trabajo, pero imagina que tuviese que iterar sobre un array de 1000 elementos.

Y en cuanto a la pregunta que planteas, creo que tendrías que intercambiar los índices que usas en la línea de append, quedaría así:

```py
columna.append(t[col][i])
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Tienes razón con lo primero, estoy empezando a programar y no vi que el range me lo simplificaba.
Por otro lado me sigue validando filas en vez de columnas, de hecho miré con un print que es lo que pasaba y se me hacia una especie de escalera con la fila seleccionada.
['1']
['1', '4']
['1', '4', '7']
['1', '4', '7', '2']
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5']
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '9']
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '9', '3']
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '9', '3', '8']
['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '9', '3', '8', '1']

Comment: Sería mejor que publicaras la solución completa.

Answer (score 0):

Para validar las filas de un Sudoku con Python, puedes usar una función similar a la siguiente:

```
def validaFila(t, fila):
    # Crea una lista con los números del 1 al 9
    numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

    # Obtiene la fila especificada del Sudoku
    fila = t[fila]

    # Verifica que no haya números repetidos en la fila
    if len(fila) != len(set(fila)):
        print("La fila tiene números repetidos")
        return False

    # Verifica que todos los números del 1 al 9 estén presentes en la fila
    if not all(num in fila for num in numbers):
        print("A la fila le faltan números")
        return False

    # Si se ha llegado hasta aquí es porque la fila es válida
    return True
```

Para usar esta función, primero debes crear una matriz (lista de listas) que represente el Sudoku y pasarla como primer argumento. Luego, debes especificar el índice de la fila que quieres validar como segundo argumento.

Por ejemplo, si quieres validar la fila 2 del siguiente Sudoku:

```
'5','3','4','6','7','8','9','1','2'],
 ['6','7','2','1','9','5','3','4','8'],
 ['1','9','8','3','4','2','5','6','7'],
```